# Why does valueForKey: on a UITextField throws an exception for UITextInputTraits properties?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, key-value-coding

Running this:

```
@try
{
    NSLog(@"1. autocapitalizationType = %d", [self.textField autocapitalizationType]);
    NSLog(@"2. autocapitalizationType = %@", [self.textField valueForKey:@"autocapitalizationType"]);
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"3. %@", exception);
}
```

Outputs this:

```
1. autocapitalizationType = 0
3. [<UITextField 0x6c15df0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key autocapitalizationType.
```

I was expecting:

```
1. autocapitalizationType = 0
2. autocapitalizationType = 0
```

This exception only happens with properties that are part of the `UITextInputTraits` protocol. *Regular* properties of a `UITextField` such has `clearButtonMode` can be accessed through `valueForKey:`.

So why can't you access `UITextInputTraits` properties with key-value coding?

Comment: Likely due to implementation details. You should file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delve into the UIKit framework and open up `UITextField.h`, you'll find:

```
@interface UITextField : UIControl <UITextInput, NSCoding> {
  @private

    UITextInputTraits  *_traits;
    UITextInputTraits  *_nonAtomTraits;
```

You'll also find that `clearButtonMode` is declared as a `@property` in the UITextField header file, but that `autocapitalizationType` (and the rest of the `UITextInputTraits` protocol) are not.

You and I don't get to see `UITextField.m`, so all we can really conclude is that Apple implemented the `UITextField`'s `UITextInputTraits` protocol in a way that's not KVC compliant. Presumably glue code somewhere converts `[myTextField autocapitalizationType]` into the appropriate value, but whatever behind-the-scenes magic is taking place stops short of `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workaround: I swizzled `valueForKey:` for every class implementing the `textInputTraits` method. If the key is a *UITextInputTraits* key, then call `valueForKey:` on the object's `textInputTraits` instead of the object itself.

Here are the implementation details: [1](https://github.com/0xced/DCIntrospect/commit/8303b1cb8b7b117ec8f7511859a5f5c9fd4e7f74), [2](https://github.com/0xced/DCIntrospect/commit/2fd0a1d493cd79dc43d70158e09bf8756557e68a) and [3](https://github.com/0xced/DCIntrospect/commit/aac1a8a82a9561aa1cef7b954183ebd096ccc857).